# Diagrams of recursive functions. Drawing recursion

Tags: recursion, diagram

I want to draw a diagram similar to this one for code below.

[image: diagram of factorial(6)]

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int x){
    if(x<3)f(x+1);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    if(x<5)f(x+2);
}
int main(void){
    f(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Second example

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int n){
    int x=0;
    static int y=1;
    --y; x+=y;
    if (n < 4) f(n+2);
    printf ("n=%d \t x=%d \t y=%d \n", n, x, y);
}
int main(void){
    f(0);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I've tried (first function).[image: diagram of f(2)]

But I need a diagram or some other way which will help me to determine what will be printed. I can't just run the code but I'd like to see the output.

Comment: You've drawn a diagram.  Is that not what you want to draw?  Its not at all clear what the pyramid diagrams have to do with the code, as the code will just print a list of values, not a 2D pyramid structure.  Illustrating the call graph would be a binary tree, not a pyramid.

Comment: I want to draw anything that will help me understand what will be printed